# Do different Makefiles with the same compiler flags produce different binaries

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, g++

Maybe this has been asked before but I could not find anything, that answers my question precisely.

I created a New arm cortex cmsis cpp project in eclipse. This gave me the default folder structure. I build the debug config and now have the generated makefiles in the debug folder. From here I can Do "make clean" and "make  and everything compiles fine. The makefiles (including the sub mk files) were to static for my needs, so I changed them to be more generic (I only tell the make where the src folders are and it scans all the folders for c and cpp files and builds All the obj files and dependencies). I also took the makefile out of the debug folder and put it one level up into the project folder. So all together, I changed the location of the makefile and made it more dynamic. Now when I run "make", everything runs fine. Everything is compiled BUT the generated .elf and .bin have a different size, compared to files, that were created with the original files. I can See in the terminal that make creates the same files in the same order with the same flags. Everything is identical except that the location of the files now is in ./ instead of ../    How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most object files and binaries contain information about the location of the source files, so that the debugger can locate them.  There may be other changes such as date and time stamps (although it's unlikely this will change the size of the output).

You can run something like `strings myprog | sort` on both old and new programs and see if the strings in your program are now different sizes.

Comment: But if the timestamp is added to the Binary, wouldn't that mean that the output files are different every time? Also, the sources and obj files and everything else is in the same location as before. Only the makefile was moved.

Comment: Yes they're different every time.  You said "the location of the files now is in ./ instead of ../" but it wasn't clear which files you meant.  In general, to get compiler output to be identical every time you rebuild it is not free and doesn't happen automatically.  It requires some effort and concentration, and often building with particular compiler options etc.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds for some notes.

Comment: No I don`t need the compiler to be deterministic. But I never worked with makefiles before (the IDE did all this for me :D) so I never took a closer look to the output files, except for the shrinkage the optimization did for me. But right now I`ve had enough of this flood of different IDEs, Plugins, HALs etc. so I decided to go the most idependent way by using makefiles. Thanks for the enlightenment :)